# How to find the windows installer version number?

Tags: windows-installer

Im trying to find out the windows installer version number for the previous release of our product.

It seems like it is a little different from the product version number, is there anyway to find out what the windows installer version number is? If I took a look at the MSI using Orca, there seems to be a product version in the Property of the MSI, something like 1.2.1234.5, would that be the windows installer version number?

Comment: Right click the file in the windows file explorer -> Properties -> Details  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During install, the Windows Installer version is stored in [VersionMsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property. Please note that version 3.1 is stored as 3.01 and 4.5 as 4.05.

If you want to determine the Windows Installer version on your machine, simply check the **msi.dll** file in `C:\Windows\system32` folder.

Comment: Is there a way to have the version shown in Apps&Features different from internal version. Lets say I have two installers and they both want to show 3.10.576 in Apps&Features, but one is build number 15670 and the other is 16700. And MSI upgrade logic should go with 16700 as latest and proceed.